# Can you run a simple node process on AWS Amplify / Lamda?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, amazon-web-services, pusher

I want to run a node js process (not a function or an express server) that connects to the change stream of a MongoDB Atlas instance so that I can publish realtime update (using pusher) to a react front ent when something in the database changes.

N.B. MongoDB Realm unfortunately does not support Sync for the Web SDK yet.

What is the correct piece of AWS infrastucutre to deploy my node js process to?

Is there a better way to ultimately achieving what I want to do?

Comment: ECS fargate most likely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a nodejs server, you can deploy one to AWS Fargate as @jordanm said in the comments https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/

You can read this tutorial to know how to achieve this:

https://medium.com/@ariklevliber/aws-fargate-from-start-to-finish-for-a-nodejs-app-9a0e5fbf6361